# Can a deferred transaction make the initial transaction fail

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, deferred-transactions

Imagine a user sending me some eosio.token to my contract and when I receive the notification, I start a new deferred transaction that fails later.

Can the deferred transaction make the initial transfer fail?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, the success or failure of the deferred transaction is independent of the action in which it is called.

The only exception is if the deferred transaction would objectively fail in the original action. For example if your deferred transaction would transfer more money from the account than is actually stored there at the time of calling the deferred transaction, then the original action will fail I believe.

Comment: thanks, when i receive the notifcation how can make it wait without failing the initial action

Comment: And what about the data stored in the table do they persist even if the deferred transaction fails or it total independance

Comment: Ask your questions as new questions, rather than comments on this question. That way it helps more people. Also when you do this you'll have to be a little clearer. What exactly are you trying to do? What do you mean with "make it wait" etc.

Comment: Can you point me where you know about this exception thank you